# How to use groupby min and rertain all field in Spring Mongo aggregation

Tags: spring, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to get by the fastest speed of each car/carId,
I have problem in getting/retaining all field when using aggregation in spring mongo .
I have check some relatvent in stackoverflow like

[mongo aggregation:- push all fields using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101792/mongo-aggregation-push-all-fields-using-spring) this was pushing to a new array using push

[How to group by max value and get full entities from MongoDB in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695254/how-to-group-by-max-value-and-get-full-entities-from-mongodb-in-spring-boot) the group by multiple field using returning many doc (instead of unique carId)

```
My race Collection was as below:
 
Race{raceId='64c2350402708c36b821e5bc', raceNum=430, trackNum='2', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=2.262371, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:12:36 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='2', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.0}, 
    
Race{raceId='64c2355f02708c36b821e5bf', raceNum=430, trackNum='2', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=2.262371, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:14:07 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='2', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.0}, 
    
Race{raceId='64c2357002708c36b821e5c2', raceNum=431, trackNum='2', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=2.262371, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:14:24 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='2', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.0}, 
    
Race{raceId='64c2357e02708c36b821e5c5', raceNum=432, trackNum='2', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=2.262371, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:14:38 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='2', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.0}, 
    
Race{raceId='64c2358d02708c36b821e5c8', raceNum=433, trackNum='2', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=2.262371, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:14:53 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='2', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.0}, 
    
Race{raceId='64c23282bc05ab7f8acd7c2a', raceNum=421, trackNum='1', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9991', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=4.298986, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:01:54 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='3', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.8806175}, 
Race{raceId='64c23294bc05ab7f8acd7c2c', raceNum=422, trackNum='1', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9991', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=4.298986, raceDatetime=Thu Jul 27 17:02:12 HKT 2023, venue='HK', rank='3', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=0.8806175}
```

My aggregtation code was below:

```
@Override
public void groupByField() {
    // Match stage
    MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("raceResulttime").gt(0)
            .and("isDnf").is(false)
            .and("raceNum").gt(0)
    );
    GroupOperation groupStage = group("carId")
            .min("raceResulttime").as("raceResulttime");
    SortOperation sortStage = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "raceResulttime");
    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("raceResulttime","rank","raceSpeed","raceNum").and("carId").previousOperation();
    // Aggregation
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage, sortStage,projectionOperation);
    AggregationResults<Race> resultss = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "race", Race.class);
    for ( Race result : resultss)
        System.out.println("4 - resultss - "+ result);
    System.out.println("5" + resultss.getMappedResults());
```

and my result got was:

```
- resultss - Race{raceId='null', raceNum=null, trackNum='null', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9992', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=1.243837, raceDatetime=null, venue='null', rank='null', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=null}
4 - resultss - Race{raceId='null', raceNum=null, trackNum='null', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9991', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=1.391792, raceDatetime=null, venue='null', rank='null', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=null}
4 - resultss - Race{raceId='null', raceNum=null, trackNum='null', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9990', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=1.483507, raceDatetime=null, venue='null', rank='null', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=null}
4 - resultss - Race{raceId='null', raceNum=null, trackNum='null', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9995', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=1.493411, raceDatetime=null, venue='null', rank='null', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=null}
4 - resultss - Race{raceId='null', raceNum=null, trackNum='null', carUser='null', carId='ZZ9996', raceStart=null, raceEnd=null, raceResulttime=1.661812, raceDatetime=null, venue='null', rank='null', isDnf=false, raceSpeed=null}
```

i would like to have all other field (get the other field while performing the  GroupOperation groupStage = group("carId")
.min("raceResulttime").as("raceResulttime");  ,thanks

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want value of fields instead of just null values?

Comment: @AjajAli yes , i want all field acquired when usiing groupby min(resulttime)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to project every data which is shown `null` in above results.

You can try projection excluding only `_id`

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().andExclude("_id");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it didnt work all other field is still null